# What language do you program in Lumberyard?

Tags: lumberyard-engine

I've looked through the FAQ on amazons site and all they mention is C++/Lua for the web service stuff. Can i assume it's C++ for the game content itself or something else (the visual script editor doesn't count)?

Comment: Given that it's just a mildly updated CryEngine plus a backend service, the [CryTek docs should help](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC1/Home).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine uses both Lua and C++ for game development and server scripting. But the visual editor isn't scripted with the visual editor.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the visual editor isn't scripting with the visual editor?"